# discrete math chapter 5 question h38

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi I got a question that I cannot solve

Suppose that n a’s and n b’s are distributed around the outside of a circle. Use mathematical induction to prove that for all integers n ≥ 1, given any such arrangement, it is possible to find a starting point so that if one travels around the circle in a clockwise direction, the number of a’s one has passed is never less than the number of b’s one has passed. For example, in the diagram shown below, one could start at the a with an asterisk.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try showing that in any configuration of a's and b's you'll always have at least one b immediately clockwise of an a, with nothing in between them (might try using a pigeonhole principle argument or induction again). After you prove this, then note that by removing this pair you can find a solution with the remaining a's and b's by your inductive hypothesis and adding the pair back in won't mess things up. For this you'll also have to make some sort of argument that any solution can be tweaked to one that begins at an a.